# How to propagate changes from child widgets if any of the child have changes?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a `QWidget`.
And inside the `QWidget`, I have a lot of other `QWidget`s, eg:- `QComboBox`, `QLineEdit`, etc ....

Now, I wanna detect if the user has made any changes (*eg:- write something in the `QLineEdit`, or changed the value on the `QComboBox`, etc ....*.)

Is there an easy way to do that?
Or do I need to capture each and every widget's signal, like this ...

```
QObject.connect(lineedit, SIGNAL("textchanged()"), doSomething)
QObject.connect(combobox, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), doSomething)
... ... ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to connect up the signals manually.